# React-router-dom errror: `You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>`

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-dom

I'm getting the `You should not use <Route> or with Router() outside a <Router>` error, but I'm already calling the route inside the router. There is my `index.js`:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./components/App";

const Wrapper = () => (
  <Router>
    <Route path="/:view?/" render={(props) => <App {...props} />} />
  </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Wrapper />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Every route is inside `App` and therefore wrapped by the `Router`. Does anyone have any idea why it could be happening here?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Please check that version of `react-router-dom` is the same as of `react-router`. Also make sure that you don't mix imports from `react-router-dom` and `react-router`

Comment: Hi, 

Thank you for your help, but both of them are in the same version (5.1.2).
Any other suggestion?

Comment: It is hard to say without a full example. The snippet you posted looks correct and the error you're getting may be caused by many reasons. The most common I wrote in my first comment, one more guess is that you have complex project structure say monorepository or just linked packages so that your bundle contains two or more copies of "react-router" that do not play well together. It would be really helpful to take a look at full project.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was happening. `MDBReact Pro` doesn't support the latest version of `react-router-dom` (what is kinda strange because their free version works well with it). 
I had to downgrade `react-router-dom` to version `4.3.1`. 
Thank you, Shlang, for the hint.  It helped me to figure out what was happening